# What causes childNodes to return #text instead of <div>?

Tags: javascript

`childNodes` occasionally gives me `#text` element instead of `<div>`

```
<div class="first-div">
    <div class="second-div">
        <div class="third-div">1</div>
        <div class="third-divs-sibling">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to access the grandchildren here like this:

```
var xxx = document.getElementsByClassName('first-div')[0];

console.log(xxx.childNodes[ 1 ].childNodes[ 1 ]);
console.log(xxx.childNodes[ 1 ].childNodes[ 2 ]);
```

Chrome gives me this:

```
<div class="third-div">1</div>
#text
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ru9v92t7/)

At first, I thought it found white space somewhere, but `console.log(xxx.childNodes[ 1 ])` returns only 3 nodes. It looks like foul magic to my untrained eye.

Does anyone have a more scientific explanation?

Comment: `.first-div` does indeed have 3 child nodes - two text nodes, and `.second-div`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whitespace creates text nodes as well. Your `#second-div` has in fact 5 children of which only 2 are elements:

- `childNodes[0]`: the line break between the opening tag and the `#third-div`
- `childNodes[1]`: the `#third-div`
- `childNodes[2]`: the line break between the `#third-div` and the `#third-divs-sibling`
- `childNodes[3]`: the `#third-divs-sibling`
- `childNodes[4]`: the line break between the `#third-divs-sibling` and the closing tag

If you're looking only for elements, you can use the [`.children` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead of `.childNodes`.

Comment: Thanks! I wish they made it this clear in the documentation

Comment: I looked at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp) and [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) but it made little sense to me because they didn't mention line breaks and code formatting explicitly. I was literally checking for selectable spaces in my editor and couldn't find any because it automates indentation. It would be nice to have something like 'auto formatting and line breaks == white space' caveat clearly emphasized in docs

Comment: MDN explicitly states "*childNodes includes all child nodes, including non-element nodes like text and comment nodes.*" on that page. Also their general DOM documentation/guide has an [entire page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace_in_the_DOM) about the subject :-)

Answer (score 2):

Those `#text` are TextNodes, which include also newlines among with tabs, spaces. Remember that [Node.childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) collection includes TextNodes also. If you don't want them, use [Node.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) which is collection of Element nodes only:

```
var xxx = document.getElementsByClassName('first-div')[0];

console.log(xxx.children[0].children[0]);
console.log(xxx.children[0].children[1]);
```

I also see that because of this confusion you assumed items being index from 1, while indexing starts with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

So, the inner values are also returned as childNodes...index 3 will give the second div (with class 'third-divs-sibling') and index 4 its text node.

```
xxx.childNodes[ 1 ].childNodes[ 1 ] => <div class="third-div">1</div>
xxx.childNodes[ 1 ].childNodes[ 2 ] => #text (1)
xxx.childNodes[ 1 ].childNodes[ 3 ] => <div class="third-divs-sibling">
xxx.childNodes[ 1 ].childNodes[ 4 ] => #text (2)
```